# How to get the most frequent level of a categorical variable in R

Tags: r, frequency

I can get the levels and frequencies of a categorical variable using `table()` function. But I need to feed the most frequent level into calculations later. How can I do that?

for example, I want to get "191" from categorical variable a.

```
> table(a)
a
  19   71   98  139  146  185  191 
 305   75  179  744    1 1980 6760
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
a <- sample(x = c(19,   71,   98,  139,  146,  185,  191), size = 1000, replace = TRUE)
tt <- table(a)
names(tt[which.max(tt)])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ll<-data.frame(table(a))
ll[which.max(ll$Freq),]
```

Example from mtcars data:

```
ll<-data.frame(table(mtcars$cyl))
 ll
  Var1 Freq
1    4   11
2    6    7
3    8   14

ll[which.max(ll$Freq),]
  Var1 Freq
3    8   14
```

Answer (score 1):

This is somehow related to the [mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2547402/is-there-a-built-in-function-for-finding-the-mode) question, where you can find many other solutions to *get the most frequent level*. I collected some one-liner solutions and also show solutions when there is *more than one* most frequent level.

```
#Create Dataset
x <- c("a","a","b","c","c")

#Some ways to get the FIRST most frequent level: "a"
names(which.max(table(x)))
names(sort(-table(x)))[1]
names(sort(-table(x))[1])

#Some ways to get ALL most frequent levels: "a" "c"
names(which(max(table(x))==table(x)))
names(table(x))[table(x)==max(table(x))]
names(table(x)[table(x)==max(table(x))])
#or the same but replace "table(x)" with "z"
z <- table(x)
names(which(max(z)==z))
names(z)[z==max(z)]
names(z[z==max(z)])
```