# Impute most frequent categorical value in all columns in data frame

Tags: r

I have the following dummy dataframe:

```
col1 = c("aa", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
        , "cc", "cc", "cc", "cc", "cc", "cc", "cc", "cc", "cc"
        , "aa", "aa", "aa", "aa", "aa", "aa", "aa", "aa", "aa", "aa", "aa")
col2 = c("aa", "aa", "aa", "aa", "aa", "aa", "aa", "aa", "aa"
         , NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
         , "bb", "bb", "bb", "bb", "bb", "bb", "bb", "bb", "bb")
col3 = c("aa", "bb", "bb"
         , NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
         , NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)
col4 = c(NA, NA, NA, 4:27)
col5 = c(28:51, NA, NA, NA)

# Construct the data frame with NAs in categorical and numeric columns
df = data.frame("col1" = col1, "col2" = col2, "col3" = col3
                , "col4" = col4, "col5" = col5, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

I would like to understand how to write a function to impute only **categorical** values i.e. `col1, col2, col3` by using the simple rules:

1. impute categorical `NA` column values with the most frequent values in that column
2. in case of ties choose the alphabetically first value i.e. `aa` has preference over `bb` (in the case for `col2`)

Could anyone please assist in writing a function which takes in `df` as an input and returns the imputed dataframe for categorical values only. `col4, col5` should remain unchanged (They have NAs but are numeric so should be ignored).

**Clarification**
For this example:

1. `col1` NAs should be imputed to be `"aa"`
2. `col2` NAs should be imputed to be `"aa"` (by alphabetic preference in ties)
3. `col3` NAs should be imputed to be `"bb"`

Thanks

Comment: what's your effort so far?

Comment: @G.Cocca - so far I have the following: ```tt <- table(df$col1)
names(tt[which.max(tt)])``` Which gets the max values. Not sure how to classify cols efficiently as categorical and then replace the NAs though. This was based on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18433647/how-to-get-the-most-frequent-level-of-a-categorical-variable-in-r

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We could create an index for non-numeric columns

```
i1 <- !sapply(df, is.numeric)
```

Create a function for Mode

```
Mode <- function(x) { 
      ux <- sort(unique(x))
      ux[which.max(tabulate(match(x, ux)))] 
}
```

and `replace` the NAs in `character` columns with the most frequent value

```
df[i1] <- lapply(df[i1], function(x)
              replace(x, is.na(x), Mode(x[!is.na(x)])))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this solution:

```
df[, sapply(df, function(x) !is.numeric(x))] <- apply(df[, sapply(df, function(x) !is.numeric(x))], 2, function(x) {x[is.na(x)] <- names(sort(table(x), decreasing = TRUE)[1]); x})
   col1 col2 col3 col4 col5
1    aa   aa   aa   NA   28
2    aa   aa   bb   NA   29
3    aa   aa   bb   NA   30
4    aa   aa   bb    4   31
5    aa   aa   bb    5   32
6    aa   aa   bb    6   33
7    aa   aa   bb    7   34
8    cc   aa   bb    8   35
9    cc   aa   bb    9   36
10   cc   aa   bb   10   37
11   cc   aa   bb   11   38
12   cc   aa   bb   12   39
13   cc   aa   bb   13   40
14   cc   aa   bb   14   41
15   cc   aa   bb   15   42
16   cc   aa   bb   16   43
17   aa   aa   bb   17   44
18   aa   aa   bb   18   45
19   aa   bb   bb   19   46
20   aa   bb   bb   20   47
21   aa   bb   bb   21   48
22   aa   bb   bb   22   49
23   aa   bb   bb   23   50
24   aa   bb   bb   24   51
25   aa   bb   bb   25   NA
26   aa   bb   bb   26   NA
27   aa   bb   bb   27   NA
```

Comment: thanks. Just for my understanding, which part checks for categorical vs numeric?

Comment: Oops...sorry, I did not include that. I will edit. I just took first 3 columns.

Comment: Edited: `sapply(df, function(x) !is.numeric(x))` checks for non-numeric columns and allows subsetting just those columns. If you explicitly want character columns, you can modify the condition from `!is.numeric()` to `is.character()`.